# Change x2go TMPDIR to somewhere other than /tmp

Tags: x2go

x2go creates large files in /tmp/.x2go-username when a session is saved.  This is causing us trouble because /tmp is filling up and no users can log in. Our /tmp directory is too small and I don't have access to increase.  We need to change the default tmp directory from /tmp to /app.

I have set TMPDIR in my .profile and also in /etc/x2go/Xsession to /app

.profile:

```
export TMPDIR=/app/
```

Xsession variables:

```
# initialize variables for use by all session scripts

OPTIONFILE=/etc/x2go/Xsession.options

SYSRESOURCES=/etc/x2go/Xresources

USRRESOURCES=$HOME/.Xresources-x2go

SYSSESSIONDIR=/etc/x2go/Xsession.d

USERXSESSION=$HOME/.xsession-x2go

USERXSESSIONRC=$HOME/.xsessionrc-x2go

ALTUSERXSESSION=$HOME/.Xsession-x2go

ERRFILE="${HOME}/.xsession-x2go-${cur_hostname}-errors"

TMPDIR=/app
```

The session still creates the tmp files in /tmp

The x2go process which is running:

```
leithner 16137     1  0 11:23 ?        00:00:00 sshfs -o idmap=user,uid=1007,gid=1001,default_permissions,ServerAliveInterval=300,IdentityFile=/home/leithner/.x2go/ssh/key.p14092,UserKnownHostsFile=/home/leithner/.x2go/ssh/key.p14092.ident SLeithne@127.0.0.1:/cygdrive/C/Users/SLeithne/X2GO~1/S-2E61~1/spool /tmp/.x2go-leithner/spool/C-leithner-50-1643045018_stDXFCE_dp32 -p 50660

leithner@entrada:/app$ echo $TMPDIR
/app
```

Where should I be changing this variable? Can it be changed?

Comment: This is a known bug need to upgrade to:                                                                                 nx-libs.x86_64           3.5.99.26-1.el7      epel7-x86_64-20220126            
nxagent.x86_64           3.5.99.26-1.el7      epel7-x86_64-20220126